# How do I know that removeEventListener was successful?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to confirm that `removeEventListener` was successful? I'm using it on a video element for the "playing"/"pause" event. The behavior I'm trying to achieve seems to be inconsistent. Here is an example of how I'm using it.

```
var playListener = function(){
  console.log("video is playing") 
}

videoElement.addEventListener("playing", playListener)
```

Somewhere else in my code

```
videoElement.removeEventListener("playing", playListener)
```

`playListener` is available where I'm using `removeEventListener` and I'm passing around the video element's id so it is the same `videoElement` I added the event listener to.

I want to know if I can do some kind of `console.log` or something to confirm that the `removeEventListener` worked.

Comment: This concept was quite a snag for me: Removing a listener requires the exact identical function for the argument. So if you're sending a bound function ( playListener.bind(this) ), it's not the exact same function (binding makes a duplicate of your original function, complete with it's own memory allocation). So you'll have to pre-bind the function to another variable, then use the pre-bound function for adding and removing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `removeEventListener` method doesn't return anything or throw an error when it does not successfully remove an event listener.  There's also no JavaScript method to access what event listeners are currently set for a given element.

As far as debugging your issue, most modern browser's developer tools do provide the capability to view event listeners. You can put a `debugger` statement in your code (or set a breakpoint) to pause execution immediately before you've called `removeEventListener`:

```
debugger;
videoElement.removeEventListener("playing", playListener);
```

Once the breakpoint is reached and execution is paused, check the event listeners from Chrome Dev Tools' Elements tab to verify that your event listener is currently set:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Event Listners]

You can also find event listeners in Firefox Dev Tools' Inspector tab:

[image: Firefox Dev Tools Event Listeners]

After verifying that your event listener is currently set, go back to the debugger (*Chrome "Sources" Tab / Firefox "Debugger" Tab*) and step through the code (*F10*) line by line.

After your call to `removeEventListener` is made, go back and check your event listeners again. If it was successful, your event listener should no longer be set. Once you're done debugging, you can then resume code execution (*F8*).

Comment: Can you share similar screenshots for microsoft Edge browser